# The difference between ( [^,]*) and (.*,) in regular expression? Using python

Tags: python, regex

When I tried to transform the string into a dict-like form, I met this problem

```
s = '&a: 12, &b:13, &c:14, &d: 15' # the string I want to convert
```

Before converting it, I tried to find all the matched results at first so I used

```
dict_form = re.compile(r'(&[a-zA-Z]*:)(.*),')
result = dict_form.findall(s)
print(result) # [('&a:', ' 12, &b:13, &c:14')]
```

It's quite unexpected, and a little bit messy

But when I tried another way to match the string:

```
dict_form1 = re.compile(r'(&[a-zA-Z]*:)([^,]*)')
result = dict_form1.findall(s)
print(result) # [('&a:', ' 12'), ('&b:', '13'), ('&c:', '14'), ('&d:', ' 15')]
```

This time, I get a better one with key and item separately stored in a tuple.

The only difference I made was (.*), into [^,]*

The first one I thought was to find anything until it matches a comma
The second one I thought was to find anything but comma

What's the difference?

Comment: When the `.*` in `.*,` matches anything, it matches *anything*, not "anything except commas". `*` is greedy by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first instance:

```
dict_form = re.compile(r'(&[a-zA-Z]*:)(.*),')
```

the `(.*)` operator is *greedy*. This means it will match everything up to the last comma, which is why you see the match extend up to `&c:14`.

In the second instance, by excluding the comma, you are forcing the match to be bound by a comma-- it's like saying "match everything until we hit a comma". This will cause the matching behavior you were expecting in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

as have been said the `.*` will be greedy and try to match as much as possible, to make it non-greedy use the question mark (`?`) as in `.*?`.  In your code:

```
dict_form = re.compile(r'(&[a-zA-Z]*:)(.*?),')
result = dict_form.findall(s)
print(result)
```

Another maybe easier solution is to just use string splits instead of regex:

```
result = [_s.split(':') for _s in s.split(',')]
```